# Fantasy CYOA Like Book With A Dragon

Tags: story-identification, choose-your-own-adventure

I remember owning this book in the '90s. I lived in Michigan at the time. The main thing I do recall is that you would turn to different pages to make a choice, and you could collect items along the way. For instance, when fighting the dragon you could perform an action or use your rope to perform a different action... if you had acquired the rope earlier. I think the book itself was green and possibly had a dragon on the cover. It may have had a man in a suit of armor too, but I really do not remember. Anyone recall this book, or anything about it?

Sorry, I wish I could be more specific. I was like 8 at the time, and I just don't have that good of a memory.

Comment: [Gamebooks](https://www.google.com/search?q=gamebook+dragon&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ-rranZjgAhX4VBUIHdDBDG0Q_AUIDygC&biw=1536&bih=724#imgrc=mC0y_4K0mH6xGM:) are very common, as are dragons in gamebooks. Can you be more specific?

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Sadly I have tried searching Google for this book many times, and I have had no luck. It does not appear to be one in this list. This is specifically a CYOA book. I do not recall much of the book, such as author, name, or date published. I just know I remember reading it in the late 90s. I also remember there were many paths and decisions to be made, and you could collect some items on your journey. I have a vague memories of fighting a dragon, and swinging from a chandelier or something. I also remember losing a few times.

Comment: Did you roll dice or simply choose an action and look up the page?  Might be one of the [_Fighting Fantasy_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fighting_Fantasy) (maybe _Deathtrap Dungeon_) books if you actually rolled dice.  Honestly, CYOA was such a big phenomenon in the 80s and 90s there were tons of different books and publishers of that type of thing.

Comment: No there were not any usage of dice or stats. It was just simply choose an action and go to that page. I know there were at least 180 pages, but very likely many more. I just remember this because I recall going to page 172 a few times.

Comment: I'd look into TSR (the publisher of Dungeons & Dragons) books then.  [Endless Quest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endless_Quest) and [AD&D Adventure Gamebooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Dungeons_%26_Dragons_Adventure_Gamebooks) should have tons of dragons.

Comment: If there had been usage of dice, I would probably have posted the Fighting Fantasy gamebook "Night Dragon" as an answer. Are you sure you didn't maybe just ignore the fighting and stat systems and play this one as a CYOA?

Answer (score 5):

*[Creatures of the Dark](https://gamebooks.org/Item/3172/Show)*, an entry in the *[Which Way Books](https://gamebooks.org/Series/29/Show)* series, features a number of unusual mechanics.  There are situations in which you have to solve math problems to proceed, and where you cannot take certain choices unless you have already been to other locations.  The latter of these sounds like what you remember with the item collection.

There is also a memorable encounter with a dragon, where you have to choose where to attack the dragon, hoping to find its weak point.  (Every dragon, apparently, should have one, just like Smaug.)  As I recall, the weak point was the dragon's tail.  Attacking it anywhere else would get you roasted.